# Apply search filter to corresponding box in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have products list need to filter by different options (Brand, Features, Price etc) Below is my HTML code and jQuery, I have a problem with filter currently as I search it filter all the box, as I am calling it using the class name. How can I make it only the corresponding (next to search box[input tag]) filter list to be filtered as I type something along with collapse/expend feature.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/144/

```html
<h3>Brands </h3> 
    <input class="filterinput" type="text"/>
    <ul class="filterlist">
        <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BlaceBerry</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">HTC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nokia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Micromax</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Features</h3>
   <input class="filterinput" type="text"/>
    <ul class="filterlist">
        <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Touch Screen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dual Sim</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3G Technology</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<h3>Another filter catagory</h3>
   <input class="filterinput" type="text"/>
    <ul class="filterlist">
        <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Touch Screen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dual Sim</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3G Technology</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY: 1.9.1**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     //<![CDATA[ 
     $(window).load(function () {
         (function ($) {
             $('.filterinput').keyup(function () {
                 var a = $(this).val();
                 if (a.length > 0) {
                     // this finds all links in the list that contain the input,
                     // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
                     var containing = $('.filterlist li').filter(function () {
                         var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a, 'i');
                         return regex.test($('a', this).text());
                     }).slideDown();
                     $('.filterlist li').not(containing).slideUp();
                 } else {
                     $('.filterlist li').slideDown();
                 }
                 return false;
             })

         }(jQuery));
         // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
         jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
             return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
         };
     });//]]> 
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".more").click(function () {
    if($(this).text() == "-"){
        $(this).text("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).text("-");
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
$('.filterinput').keyup(function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length > 0) {
        var containing = $('.filterlist li').filter(function () {
            var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a, 'i');
            return regex.test($('a', this).text());
        }).slideDown();
        $(this).next().find('li').not(containing).slideUp(); //changed
    } else {
        $(this).next().find('li').slideDown(); //changed
    }
    return false;
})
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/145/)

Comment: Thank you Hiral, Can you please do little more help to make these box collapse able and expendable.

Comment: @user1610100 welcome :) please elaborate m not getting your point

Comment: Added the screenshot, where you can see '+' symbol to expend collapse this panel, And that div tag is scrollable(for example 100+ brands not go very longer in page). That is what i want to implement : Scrollable and collapse+expend

Comment: Hiral code not working with  <div class="outer">
<div class="span3">
<span>Features</span><span class="more">-</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <input class="filterinput" type="text" />
    <ul class="filterlist">
        <li><a href="#">Android</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Touch Screen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dual Sim</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3G Technology</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Hiral, would you like to see one more question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841196/hide-show-table-rows-based-on-checkbox-and-data-element , since nobody answered on this with proper code as you here.

Comment: Hi Hiral, i have an issue with search filter : Browser hang when 500+ records to search. See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/154/ and try to search any brands, Can we do something on this?

Comment: @user1610100 because you are handling it client side. Client cannot handle such heavy operations. Use server-side coding for this.

Comment: Hiral, Any example or fiddle?