# Hide/Show table rows based on checkbox and data element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the rows in my table, as i checked on check box and that data element is not true in the table.

- Another experiment

: Can i also do the order by using the data element and sort by drop down list, look on tr tags(price, name, rating) ?

```
<div class="filter-list">         
<label><input type="checkbox" value="EMI"/>EMI</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="COD"/>COD</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Return-Policy"/>Return Policy</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Discount"/>Discount</label>

<select id="sortby">
<option value="price:asc">Price: Low to High</option>
<option value="price:desc">Price: High to Low</option>
<option value="rating:desc">Store Rating</option>
<option value="rating:desc">A-Z</option>
<option value="rating:desc">Z-A</option>
</select>
</div>

<table id="productsprice">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-cod="1" data-emi="0" data-returnpolicy="1" data-discount="1" data-rating="3" data-price="45000" data-name="ebay">
            <td>COD: YES</td>
            <td>EMI: No</td>
            <td>Return Policy: 30 days</td>
            <td>Price: 45000</td>
            <td>Discount : 300</td>
        </tr>
 <tr data-cod="1" data-emi="0" data-returnpolicy="1" data-discount="1" data-rating="3" data-price="45000" data-name="sears">
            <td>COD: YES</td>
            <td>EMI: No</td>
            <td>Return Policy: 30 days</td>
            <td>Price: 42000</td>
            <td>Discount : 300</td>
        </tr>
 <tr data-cod="0" data-emi="1" data-returnpolicy="" data-discount="0" data-rating="4" data-price="48000" data-name="walmart">
            <td>COD: NO</td>
            <td>EMI: YES</td>
            <td>Return Policy: 30 days</td>
            <td>Price: 48000</td>
            <td>Discount : Not Available</td>
        </tr>
 <tr data-cod="1" data-emi="1" data-returnpolicy="1" data-discount="0" data-rating="5" data-price="45000.50" data-name="amazon">
            <td>COD: YES</td>
            <td>EMI: YES</td>
            <td>Return Policy: 30 days</td>
            <td>Price: 45000.50</td>
            <td>Discount : Not Avaialable</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".filter-list").change(function(){
    $("#productsprice").children('tbody').children('tr').each(function(){
        var match = false;
        $(this).attr('data-cod').each(function() {
            if($(this).text() == $(".filter-list").val()) match = true;
        });

 // if data tag in <tr> found as not 1(true). toggle the hidden class to that rows and so on for each rows
    });
});
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/9TTPS/9/

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.  If you want true table filter/sort functionality you should use a grid library like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3achange#jqgrid_4.5.4_changes_and_fixes)

Comment: Mike, This would require another JS library call in my page, which will increase the load and impact on performance. Can't we do this using the jquery library 1.9.1 only?

Comment: Mike, i was most interested with Jquery only, Can't you help there?

Comment: You are looking for some pretty complicated functionality.  It's obviously possible but I'm not (and don't hold your breath for others) going to write out this custom solution for you.  If you can't figure out where to begin I don't suggest going this route unless you are doing this purely for self-education.  Check out one of the grid libraries, or look into knockout.js...which may fit your needs even better.  It's lightweight, fast and awesome.

Comment: Mike, i found something the same as per my requirement here : http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/samsung-galaxy-s3-msp1765 and JS is here : http://www.mysmartprice.com/msp/js/single.js      Can you please help me to put this in fiddle and work with my table.